# creating featured text in MS word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, office365, windows-11, text-formatting

I am working on a book in MS Office.

In my book, there are many texts and phrases that I need to feature (in other words highlight to catch the reader's attention) something exactly like I've shown in the example images below:

[image: text surround by a circle]

[image: text surround by a circle]

How do you create a 'featured text' section like this, as shown in the picture, in MS Office Word.

Comment: Are these quoted excerpts from the book's main body?  Or are they independent from the typescript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to Insert -> Shapes. Select a shape and draw where it on your page.
2. Right click on the shape, then click on Add Text. Enter the "featured" text.
3. Right click on the shape, select Wrap Text, then select Tight.
4. Optionally, set Shape Outline and/or Shape Fill to your desired color(s).

[image]

Comment: THanks buddy @Reddy , this is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

### I prefer to use a Frame, but it can only be a rectangle, not an oval.

In Word, a shape is a textbox and text in it is treated as being outside the document, whereas text in a Frame is treated as being inside the document.

Here is [my page comparing Textboxes and Frames](https://addbalance.com/word/frames_textboxes.htm#StartPage). It is fairly long and contains information about [using a Frame for marginal text](https://addbalance.com/word/frames_textboxes.htm#sidebars) and on [how to create a Frame](https://addbalance.com/word/frames_textboxes.htm#CreatingFrames).

A key advantage to using a Frame is that you can define a paragraph style that has the Frame already setup. I have one for left side of page and a separate style for right side of page.

[image: screenshot showing frame use]

The above shows completely marginal text. You can also have frames that have text wrap around them. The screenshot below shows this with borders and with inside and outside frames.

[image: screenshot]

See also [True Marginal Text](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/MarginalText.htm#TrueMarginalText) by Word MVP Suzanne Barnhill.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and most efficient way is to download word templates from the Internet, some of which are very exquisite and very convenient to write. If you want to create your own templates, you need to be proficient in word page layouts, artistic fonts, backgrounds, and so on. In the Word Developer tab, you can customize the new features.